# Django 'bool' object has no attribute '_committed'

Tags: python, django

Well, I have a field type FileField and when I try to delete the contents of it, returns me this error message: 'bool' object has no attribute '_committed' `
To upload works normally, the problem is only when I try to remove the file that was sent.

My View:

```
try:
    profile = request.user.get_profile()
    company = profile.company
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    raise Http404 

if request.method == 'POST':
   data = request.POST
   profile_form = EditUserProfileForm(data=data)
   company_form = EditCompanyForm(data=data, files=request.FILES)

  if profile_form.is_valid() and company_form.is_valid():
     profile_form.save(profile)
     company_form.save(company)
     messages.info(request, 'Dados atualizados com sucesso.')
     return HttpResponseRedirect('')
 else:
    profile_form.save(profile)
    company_form.save(company)  #Error here.
    messages.info(request, 'Dados atualizados com sucesso.')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('')
```

Edit: The full traceback

```
Traceback:
File "/home/vanderson/.virtualenvs/cargobr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/vanderson/.virtualenvs/cargobr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vanderson/Sites/cargo-br/cargobr/../cargobr/apps/accounts/views.py" in edit
  407.                     company_form.save(company)
File "/home/vanderson/Sites/cargo-br/cargobr/../cargobr/apps/accounts/forms.py" in save
  147.         company.save()
File "/home/vanderson/.virtualenvs/cargobr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  460.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "/home/vanderson/.virtualenvs/cargobr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  484.             signals.pre_save.send(sender=origin, instance=self, raw=raw, using=using)
File "/home/vanderson/.virtualenvs/cargobr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py" in send
  172.             response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
File "/home/vanderson/.virtualenvs/cargobr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy_thumbnails/signal_handlers.py" in find_uncommitted_filefields
  20.             if not getattr(instance, field.name)._committed:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /editar-cadastro/
Exception Value: 'bool' object has no attribute '_committed'
```

Edit: EditCompanyForm:

```
class EditCompanyForm(CompanyForm):

    class Meta:
        model = accounts.models.Company
        exclude = ('verified', 'rating')


    def save(self, company):
        company.insurance_policy = self.cleaned_data['insurance_policy']
        company.save()
        return company
```

Comment: What is the full traceback of the exception? In the error view in the browser, use the 'show traceback as text' link first.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add that information.

Comment: local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy_thumbnails/signal_handlers.py in find_uncommitted_filefields:
if not getattr(instance, field.name)._committed:

Comment: I did ask for the *full* traceback; there is a wealth of information in such a traceback. What method triggered the signal, for example. Which of your two models has a `FileField` for example?

Comment: I edited. My Model Company has the FileField

Comment: Now we can move on: What is the definition of `EditCompanyForm`? What is the name of the `FileField` entry?

Comment: I edited. Is the code.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same error, the reason was I didn't set enctype in my form, 
`<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/foo/">`

Answer (score 2):

This response comes very late but might help others, as I had a similar problem today. I received the same error message in my views.py at the same line, which occurred whenever I wanted to save an empty ImageField.

My view:

```
def recipe_new(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RecipeForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        recipe = form.save(commit=False)
        recipe.author = request.user
        recipe.published_date = timezone.now()
        recipe.save()  #Error here.
        return redirect('recipe_detail', pk=recipe.pk)
else:
    form = RecipeForm()
return render(request, 'blog/recipe_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

My form:

```
class RecipeForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Recipe
    fields = ('title', 'image', 'is_vegan', 'is_veggie', 'cuisine',
              'contained_allergen', 'instruction')
```

My model:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images", default=True)
    is_vegan = models.BooleanField("Vegan", default=False)
    is_veggie = models.BooleanField("Vegetarisch", default=False)
    etc.
```

It turned out that the parameter `default=True` in the ImageField caused the problem. After deleting it the error message disappeared.